# Consistency in navigation

Tags: navigation, dropdown, consistency

Is it going against best practice to have some items in the main navigation clickable and other items not clickable they just reveal a drop down? Should the pages that reveal a drop down have a landing page?

Comment: Related: [Dropdown navigation menus - should top menu option link to content?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/22376/dropdown-navigation-menus-should-top-menu-option-link-to-content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does. You need to make the drop-down navigation item clickable to make the link accessible to touch interface users.

You don't need not to have a landing page for the drop down-click, just make the drop down-item stay open when the top navigation have been clicked or hovered.

---

<sup>**Off Topic:** Here are some useful scripts for implementation: [Drop-Down Menu: 30+ Useful Scripts To Enhance Header Navigation](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/drop-down-menu-30-free-scripts-to-enhance-header-navigation/)</sup>